# How to select (highlight) all text in table using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to select (highlight) all text in table using JavaScript/jQuery like this?

[image: https://s9.postimg.org/3str2tckf/Ask_Select_Table.png]

```
<table id="HighlightThis">
<thead>
    <tr><th>Num.<th>Name
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>1.<td>Cat
    <tr><td>2.<td>Bird
    <tr><td>3.<td>Fish
</tbody>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse this can be your solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function should work in all mainstream browsers, credit [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down)

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
        var body = document.body, range, sel;
        if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
            range = document.createRange();
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            try {
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            } catch (e) {
                range.selectNode(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        } else if (body.createTextRange) {
            range = body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.select();
        }
    }
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tony7/y040dLd6/)